# How to convert from 2d world coordinates to 2d screen coordinates?

Tags: c++, 2d, rendering, sdl, game-development

I am designing a 2d platformer tile-based game using SDL. I am having trouble with converting from world coordinates to screen coordinates. I defined (0, 0) as the top left for both the screen and the world and (x, y) as the bottom right.

Currently, I am storing the map data like so:

`"." is an air tile`

`"#" is a grass tile`

`"i" is an iron tile`

`"p" is a wooden plank tile`

`"c" is the top layer of the ice`

`"b" is the bottom layers of the ice`

```
...iiiiii...pppppp..cccccc...........................................
...iiiiii...pppppp..b....b...........................................
...iiiiii...p....p..b....b...........................................
...iiiiii...p....p..b....b...........................................
...iiiiii...p....p..b....b...........................................
...iiiiii...p....p..b....b...........................................
...iiiiii...p....p..bbbbbb...........................................
...iiiiii...pppppp..bbbbbb...........................................
...iiiiii...pppppp..bbbbbb...........................................
...iiiiii...pppppp..bbbbbb...........................................
...iiiiii...pppppp..bbbbbb...........................................
...iiiiii...pppppp..bbbbbb...........................................
#####################################################################
.....................................................................
.....................................................................
.....................................................................
.....................................................................
.....................................................................
.....................................................................
.....................................................................
.....................................................................
.....................................................................
.....................................................................
.....................................................................
....................................................................#
```

I am loading the map like so, in which the top left is (0, 0):

```
typedef struct Tile {
    char texture_id;
    int x;
    int y;
} Tile;

Map::Map(std::string raw_map_data) {
    // Initialize private variables
    this->unparsed_map_data= raw_map_data;

    // Split the map data into a std::vector<std::string> based off of newlines
    std::vector<std::string> map_data_split = split_string(raw_map_data, "\n");

    // Next, convert the map data to a vector Tile structs
    int cur_x = 0;
    int cur_y = 0;
    std::vector<Tile> tiles_processed;
    Tile tile;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < map_data_split.size(); i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < map_data_split[i].size(); j++) {
            tile.x = cur_x;
            tile.y = cur_y;
            tile.texture_id = map_data_split[i][j];
            tiles_processed.push_back(tile);
            cur_x += TILE_WIDTH;
        }
        cur_x = 0;
        cur_y += TILE_HEIGHT;
    }
    this->tiles_parsed = tiles_processed;
    //std::reverse(this->tiles_parsed.begin(), this->tiles_parsed.end());
    DebugTiles(this->tiles_parsed); // DEBUG: used to print tiles to find errors
}
```

I have set the camera coordinates as the world coordinates of the top-left point of the window. Additionally, the player never leaves the center of the screen. Furthermore, the transformation that I am using to go from the world coordinates to the screen coordinates is as follows: **`screen coordinates = camera coordinates - world coordinates of tile`**

```
void Camera::Render(std::vector<Tile> tiles_to_render, SDL_Texture* player_texture) {
    // Render the scene
    for (size_t i = 0; i < tiles_to_render.size(); i++) {
        if (tiles_to_render[i].texture_id != '.') {
            // world_pos_tl is an SDL_Rect containing the camera coordinates
            SDL_Rect dstrect = {this->world_pos_tl.x - tiles_to_render[i].x, this->world_pos_tl.y - tiles_to_render[i].y, TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT};
            SDL_RenderCopy(this->renderer, this->textures[tiles_to_render[i].texture_id], NULL, &dstrect);
        }
    }


    // Render the character (always in center of screen)
    SDL_Rect player_dstrect = {(WIDTH / 2) - TILE_WIDTH, (HEIGHT / 2) - TILE_HEIGHT, TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT};
    SDL_RenderCopy(this->renderer, player_texture, NULL, &player_dstrect);
}
```

However, when I compile and run, I get the following result, as the world is rotated 270 degrees.

The result of running the code:

[image: rendered image]

Comment: So what happens when you run screen co-ordinates = world co-ordinates of tile?

Comment: Then there is no movement and the image is stationary

Answer (score 0):

Special thanks to ***Gorbit99*** on the "One Lone Coder" discord server who figured this out for me.

The issue is that it is supposed to be **screen position = world position - camera position.** The reason for this is because when you move an object to the left and the camera stays still, the object should move left. But if the camera moves to the left and the object stays still, it should look like the object's moving to the right.

Side note: I am overusing the keyword, `this` a lot, as it is only meant to be used when a variable in a function has the same name as a class member and you want to specify that you want to use the class member. Therefore, in practice, the keyword `this` should rarely be used.